# 32 bit version of SonarQube with 64 bit java

Tags: java, sonarqube, wrapper

I'm a student trying to produce clean code for class and we've been guided towards sonar to do so. I cannot launch my server using the StartSonar.bat. I get this error:

> WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library 'wrapper.dll'.
>   jvm 1    |           The file is located on the path at the following location but
>   jvm 1    |           could not be loaded:
>   jvm 1    |             C:\Users\ribou\Desktop\Logiciel\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\bin\windows-x86-64.\lib\wrapper.dll
>   jvm 1    |           Please verify that the file is readable by the current user
>   jvm 1    |           and that the file has not been corrupted in any way.
>   jvm 1    |           One common cause of this problem is running a 32-bit version
>   jvm 1    |           of the Wrapper with a 64-bit version of Java, or vica versa.
>   jvm 1    |           This is a 32-bit JVM.

I cannot find a 32 bits version of java 11 nor or 64 bit version of SonarQube. I could really use some help.

Comment: The SonarStart.bat is dependent on the windows bit size. Are you using correct version along with your windows version? Is your windows 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: It's a 64 bit version

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned you couldn't find 32 bits version of java 11. It seems like default JVM on your machine is 32 bit only. Look at the error like "This is a 32-bit JVM.". You either need to install 64 bit Java with 64 bit SonarQube or both 32 bits. Because the error clearly suggests, you have different versions.

Comment: The thing is: I can't find a 64 bits version of SonarQube nor a 32 bit version of java

Comment: Was there ever a resolution for this?